# Twitter Bootstrap navbar hover active with dropdowns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure my title is not the easiest to understand. I'll try and explain what I am trying to do.

If you go to this URL (http://buffalo.demo.libguides.com) and rollover over the global navigation (Find Library Materials, My Account, Get Help, etc) you'll see the hover is blue. But when you rollover the dropdown menu it goes back to grey. I want it to stay blue while hovering on the dropdown.

I had this working with an old version of Bootstrap, but I'm having trouble with this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a URL with the old version that works. http://library.buffalo.edu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```css
.content-block .navbar-nav > li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #062198;
}
```

Right now `.content-block .navbar-nav > li > a:hover` on line *1466* of *style-gudes.css* is controlling the background color of the navigation item. Since you're using a hover state on the anchor element which doesn't wrap the nested `ul` that forms the dropdown, it will not remain blue and revert to the default color once the cursor moves off that element.

Hook into the hover state of the `li` that wraps the dropdown `ul`. Target the anchor element when that `li` is being hovered, `li:hover a`. Now, whenever the the dropdown's parent `li` is hovered, the `a` will also be styled when that `li` is hovered.

Comment: It turns it the right background color, but then the text color reverts back to the original state and won't stay white: http://buffalo.demo.libguides.com/

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect!